# Restore deleted emails Exchange Purges folder EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Hi there's emails within the Recoverable Items\Purges folder of Exchange mailboxes i'm trying to restore. Now I know how to restore the emails using say EWS however, i'd like to restore the items from the actual folder the emails existed in, rather than just saying anything with IPM.Note will be put back into the Well Known Folder Inbox. Anyone know if this can be done or how? I couldn't see a proptag for this..

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

No Exchange doesn't provide any properties that indicate the folder an Item was deleted from (this would be a nice feature and has been requested in the past).

Comment: [Please stop using taglines in all of your answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021)